# ¿Cómo enviar una imagen desde Xamarin Android a WhatsApp?

Tags: imagen, android-imageview, xamarin.android, whatsapp

Quiero poder enviar un archivo de tipo Image, por WhatsApp, desde Xamarin Android, hasta ahorita sólo pude enviar Texto, si alguien pudiera ayudarme, o darme un enlace con algo de documentación para eso, busqué pero no logre encontrar mucho en C#, ésto es lo que tengo para el envío de texto

```
#region WhatsApp
string whatsapp = "com.whatsapp";
        bool VerificarApp(String uri)
        {
            try
            {
                ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(uri, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
                return true;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void EnviarWhatsApp()
        {
            if (VerificarApp(whatsapp))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
                intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Prueba de envío de WhatsApp desde Xamarin Android, Oscar N.");
                intent.SetType("text/plain");
                //intent.SetType("image");
                intent.SetPackage(whatsapp);
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "WhatsApp no está instalado. No se pudo enviar el mensaje", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya pude hacerlo ;)

```
public void SharedImageSocialNetworks(string title, string content)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                        return;

                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.halo);
                    var tempFilename = "Test.png";
                    var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
                    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, tempFilename);
                    using (var os = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        b.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
                    }
                    b.Dispose();
                    var imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"file://{sdCardPath}/{tempFilename}");
                    var intent = new Intent();
                    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
                    intent.SetType("image/*");
                    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, content);
                    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, imageUri);
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                    StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, title));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Error: " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
```